how to force git pull to generate conflict file instead of stashing them
I haven't find a proper solution to this one issue.
I remember long time ago that this was my git maybe svn behavior to actually overwrite my local change but with diff file so you need to solve conflict yourself before pushing your changes.
Is it possible to set some config in git to always pull my change and automatically create diff files for me to solve.

I'm not sure this is what you want, but you can copy the diff file that's written, then abort the action.

What do you have in config for merge.autoStash? (or alternatively rebase.autoStash if you also have pull.rebase set to true) Unless these are explicitly set to true, a pull should not result in an automatic stash. Check git config --get merge.autoStash.

None of rebase.autoStash or merge.autoStash is set in my current git config

I must say I have some difficulty to understand your question. a. you say, in the title "stashing", do you mean "staging" ? as in: the conflicts show up in git status ? b. git pull is the same as running git fetch followed by git merge. So when you reach the step when you have conflicts, you already have downloaded the remote changes, stored under origin/main (<- or origin/branch_name if you are working on a different branch). Perhaps you are looking for commands to cancel the merge, and check what are the downloaded changes ?

Maybe I'm the one confuse in this case I think I had --rebase always added to my git pull but if simple git pull does a fetch and merge that's probably what I was looking for.
